# Can't understand function behavior - isprime()

Tags: python, function, for-loop, primes

I have constructed two functions. The first (not important but related since it is called in the second one) tells whether a number is a prime:

```
def is_prime(i):
    if i == 1:
        print("prime")
    if i == 2:
        print("not prime")
    for d in range(2, i):
        if i % d != 0:
            d = d+1
            if d == i:
                print('prime')
                break
        if i % d == 0:
            print('not prime')
            break
```

I want to be able to make this function count all the primes from `1` up till `p`.
When I ask it to append it to the list - it returns an empty list and all the values individually.

```
def prime_counting(p):
    list_of_primes = []
    for n in range (p+1):
        if is_prime(n) == "prime":
            list_of_primes.append(n)
```

[image: Instead of putting it in the list- it maps them separately]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: **Note:** 1 is not a prime.

Comment: Sorry about that. Stack overflow asks me to wait 7 minutes each time before I can accept an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Note: I didn't check the *logic* of your `is_prime()` function)</sub>
The glaring error in your code is that the function `is_prime()` does not `return` anything, it just `print`s. You want it to `return True` or `False` depending if the number is prime or not. Change it to do so.

Then you can check:

```
if is_prime(n) == True:
    list_of_primes.append(n)
```

Edit: as stated (correctly) in the comments, a more "pythonic" way of writing this kind of statement is:

```
if is_prime(n):
    list_of_primes.append(n)
```

Since `is_prime()` will return `True` or `False` (so there's no need to compare with them).

Comment: More pythonic is `if is_prime(n):`

Comment: If `is_prime(n)` returns `True` or `False`, do you need to compare that against `True`? Possibly it's enough to just use `if is_prime(n):` ...?

Comment: You are both right, since the OP is a beginner (I assume), I figured it would be a clearer approach. I will edit my answer with this though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few flaws in your code, but the one you are asking about is:

You are looking at the return value of `is_prime()` with

```
if is_prime(n) == "prime":
```

but `is_prime()` does not contain any return statements.

Here is a slightly modified version that actually returns a value from `is_prime()`:

```
def is_prime(i):
    if i == 1:
        return "prime"
    if i == 2:
        return "not prime"

    for d in range(2, i):
        if i % d != 0:
            d = d + 1
            if d == i:
                return "prime"
        if i % d == 0:
            return "not prime"


def prime_counting(p):
    list_of_primes = []
    for n in range(p+1):
        if is_prime(n) == "prime":
            print("added %s" % n)
            list_of_primes.append(n)
    return list_of_primes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(prime_counting(3))
```

If you instead return a boolean value `return True` or `return False` you will be able to just do:

```
if is_prime(n):
   do_something()
```

or even use "comprehension" like so:

`prime_list = [n for n in range(1, p+1) if is_prime(n)]`

Comment: While your main point is correct, it is *very bad practice* to `return` a string like that from a function. It is very error-prone (why "not prime" and not "Not prime" or "Not Prime" or "Not prime"?...) and should not be done.

Comment: I definitly agree and it is mentioned in the code that it in fact is bad practice. Though answering a question with code that is completely re-written may confuse more than it helps.